# Select with SVG icon

Tags: blueprintjs

is there any way to make  dropdown menu to have arrows rendered with SVG instead of with font?

The following example code renders arrow icon with icon font:

```
<div class="pt-select">
  <select>
    <option selected>Choose an item...</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This is how the component is rendered without font imported to project:

[image: SelectBox]

I don't want to import icon fonts for a reason.
I'm using BluePrint 2.0, but if the SVG solution exists in 3.0, I'm happy to upgrade.